# select-xml does not return any results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the powershell command select-xml to select data from an xml file. When I run the command below no results or errors are returned. I expect a list of the editions to be returned to the screen. What's wrong with this?

```
PS C:\> select-xml -path "C:\t.xml" -xpath "//edition" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
PS C:\>
```

The XML file (C:\t.xml) is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Book>
    <projects>
      <project name="Book1" date="2009-01-20">
        <editions>
           <edition language="English">En.Book1.com</edition>
           <edition language="German">Ge.Book1.Com</edition>
           <edition language="French">Fr.Book1.com</edition>
           <edition language="Polish">Pl.Book1.com</edition>
        </editions>
      </project>
    </projects>
  </Book>
```

Comment: I see it working
PS H:\> Select-Xml -Path C:\scripts\t.xml -XPath "//edition" | % { $_.node.InnerXML }
En.Book1.com
Ge.Book1.Com
Fr.Book1.com
Pl.Book1.com
PS H:\>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I know what's wrong. There was one white space character before the first node of the XML declaration. Really annoying. I tried your first line:

```
PS H:\> $xml = ([xml](Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\t.xml)).Book.Projects.Project
```

It errored with:

> "..The XML declaration must be the
>   first node in the document, and no
>   white space characters are allowed to
>   appear before it..."

I'm sure that the select-xml should fail in the question with this same error when attempting to read an xml file. The xml file rendered fine in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to do this is:

```
PS H:\> $xml = ([xml](Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\t.xml)).Book.Projects.Project
PS H:\> $xml.editions | select -ExpandProperty Edition

language                                                    #text
--------                                                    -----
English                                                     En.Book1.com
German                                                      Ge.Book1.Com
French                                                      Fr.Book1.com
Polish                                                      Pl.Book1.com
```

Comment: Running the first line gave me an error which I then used to solve the problem. +1 for a step towards the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$_.node returns a System.Xml.XmlElement which does not have an innerXml property

```
Select-Xml -Path C:\t.xml -XPath "//edition" | 
    % {$_.node} | get-member | out-gridview
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple more options:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<Book>
  <projects>
    <project name="Book1" date="2009-01-20">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">En.Book1.com</edition>
        <edition language="German">Ge.Book1.Com</edition>
        <edition language="French">Fr.Book1.com</edition>            
        <edition language="Polish">Pl.Book1.com</edition>         
      </editions>       
    </project>     
  </projects>   
</Book> 
'@

$xml | Select-Xml '//edition/text()' | Foreach {"$_"}

$xml | Select-Xml '//edition' |  Foreach {$_.Node.InnerText}
```